# Nested XML Serialization C#

Tags: c#, xml

I need to create nested Xml with serialization. I have two Lists with data that have to generate nested xml filtered by Number.

The lists:

```
List<Person> personList = new List<Person>();
personList.Add(new Person{
Number = 1,
Name = "Dean"
 });

personList.Add(new Person{
  Number = 2,
 Name = "Mike"
 });

 List<Home> homeList= new List<Home>();
  homeList.Add(new Home{
 Number = 2,
 City= "Paris",
 State = "France"
 });

homeList.Add(new Home{
Number = 1,
City= "London",
State = "England"
 });
```

So next i have class that i use for serialization:

```
public class CreateXML
{
[XElement(ElementName = "Home")]
List<Home> homeList= new List<Home>();
[XElement(ElementName = "Person")]
List<Person> personList = new List<Person>();
}
```

Method for creating XML:

```
 public void Serialize(CreateXML list)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CreateXML));
        using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"D:\XmlTEST.txt"))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, list);
        }
    }
```

Now it generates Xml file first with all Person data then with Home data.

Actual output:

```
  <Person>
    <number>1<number>
    <name>Dean</name>
  </Person>
  <Person>
    <number>2<number>
    <name>Mike</name>
  </Person>
  <Home>
    <number>1</number>
    <city>London</city>
    <state>England</state>
  </Home>
  <number>2</number>
  <city>Paris</city>
  <state>London</state>
</Home>
```

Wanted ouput:

```
<Person>
  <number>1<number>
  <name>Dean</name>
  <Home>
    <number>1</number>
    <city>London</city>
    <state>England</state>
  </Home>
</Person>
<Person>
  <number>2<number>
  <name>Mike</name>
  <Home>
    <number>2</number>
    <city>Paris</city>
    <state>France</state>
  </Home>
</Person>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the difference between the desired and actual output?

Comment: if you want to have an element Home inside the Person at the output xml structure, you need to add field with type Home to Person class. Or with what you stuck?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to associate a certain `Home` with the `Person` Dean:

```
<Person>
  <number>1</number>
  <name>Dean</name>
  <Home>
    <number>1</number>
    <city>London</city>
    <state>England</state>
  </Home>
</Person>
```

Yet in your code you do not associate these two entities:

```
personList.Add(new Person {
    Number = 1,
    Name = "Dean"
});

homeList.Add(new Home{
    Number = 1,
    City= "London",
    State = "England"
});
```

*In the above example entities are completely unrelated -- you need to somehow relate them.*

One way you can relate these entites is by defining a `Home` property on the `Person` type:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public Home Home { get; set; }
}
```

Then ditch `homeList` and assign `Home` instances to `Person` instances:

```
List<Person> personList = new List<Person>();
personList.Add(new Person
{
    Number = 1,
    Name = "Dean",
    Home = new Home
    {
        Number = 1,
        City = "London",
        State = "England"
    }
});
```

Output:

```
<personList>
  <Person>
    <Name>Dean</Name>
    <Number>1</Number>
    <Home>
      <Number>2</Number>
      <City>Paris</City>
      <State>France</State>
    </Home>
  </Person>
  <Person>
    <Name>Mike</Name>
    <Number>2</Number>
    <Home>
      <Number>1</Number>
      <City>London</City>
      <State>England</State>
    </Home>
  </Person>
</personList>
```

**Update**

Based on your comment, you can dynamically assign to the `Home` property like this:

```
foreach (var home in homeList)
{
    foreach (var person in personList)
    {
        if (home.Number == person.Number)
        {
            person.Home = home;
        }
    }
}
```

Bare in mind that, if there is no corresponding house number, the `House` property will remain `null`.

Comment: Yes that's what i want to do, but want to filter the result, not to do hardcoded. Example Home = new Home{ if(Home.Number == Person.Number } then to list all the data.

Comment: @PetarS Updated my answer. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: that's what i looking for, i was trying to do the same thing all day, but still having problems where to put the foreach statement.

Comment: @PetarS Awesome. You can put it beneath your `personList` and `homeList` variables. If this answered your question, please mark it as accepted!